# code for uptime availability of an API call

Tags: python, perl, availability-monitoring

I have a Perl script that runs every 5 minutes which does an API call. This API call consist of a REST call to authenticate to the database. If I authenticate successfully, it returns an 'ok' or a '1'.

I've been tasked to give our front end developer the uptime availability of this API call. For example, something to the nature of '99.98888' that reflects a range; for example, a range of 90 days or possibility 365 days.

Here is the script that does the API call.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;
use JSON;


## Perl's way of slurping the xml file
my $message = do {
  open my $fh, '<', '/usr/lib/xymon/server/ext/States/Puerto-Rico/credentials.xml' or die "Could not open file: $!";
  local $/;
  <$fh>;
};


    my $start = `date +%s.%N`;
    my $webpage = "https://xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx.asp";

    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    my $response = $ua->post($webpage, Content_Type => 'text/xml',
                                            Content => $message);
    my $end = `date +%s.%N`;
    my $eventtime = `date +%c`;
    my $time = $end - $start;
    my $response_time = sprintf "%.1f", $time;


    if ( $response->is_success) {

my $xml = new XML::Simple;
my $x = $response->decoded_content;

# read XML file
my $data = $xml->XMLin($x);



my $success =  $data->{'success'};



if ( $response_time < 5 && $success == '1' )
{
print "good\n";
}
```

I need to add the code or mathematical formula to give me the uptime availability of this API call for 90 or 365 days (script can run every 1 or 5 minutes) in this Perl script so it can populate a text file. Then the front end developer will retrieve the data from the text file and make a pretty web page or JavaScript call. Any hints will be appreciated and I could write this in python too.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to be to do this with 2 scripts. The monitoring script would  write a date-time stamp and a 1 or 0 for success or failure to a new line in a txt results file every run.  Another script would run maybe once per day and parse the results file counting the number of fail responses compared to overall responses. It is then a simple percentage calculation to get the result which you could put in a txt file that the front end guy could read.

As you loop through the file reading each line once you get to results 90 or 365 days from today you start writing the results back out to a file.  When complete replace the existing results file with the new one.

If you have access to a database then you could use the same principal but it would be more flexible.